# question on weekly aggregation using python

Tags: python, datetime

Given a list of timestamps in sequential order, return a list of lists grouped by week (7 days) using the first timestamp as the starting point.

for example:

ts = ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-08', '2019-02-01','2019-02-05']

output = [['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'],['2019-01-08'],['2019-02-01', '2019-02-05']]

```
ts = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns = ['date'])
ts['week'] = pd.to_datetime(ts.date).dt.week
ts.groupby('week')['date'].apply(list).tolist()
```

is there a way of solving the above without using pandas?

Comment: `pandas` has a datetime datatype: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html. You could convert those strings to `datetime` objs, compute the difference between them, and then groupby dates that are within 7 days of each other. If you're not using `pandas` you could use python's native datetime: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Your output doesn't correspond with the text in your assignment. The last two days are in separate weeks, not in the same week.

Comment: I would use itertools.groupby with a custom lambda function as key to solve this problem. The lambda function should return the integer division of number of days since the first date by 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime as dt
curr = '2019-01-01'
idx = 0
dic = defaultdict(list)
for i in ts:
 if ( dt.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') -  dt.strptime(curr, '%Y-%m-%d')).days < 7 :
     dic[idx].append(i)
 else:
    curr = i
    idx += 1
    dic[idx].append(i)
print(dic.values())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would have solved it:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby

inp = ['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-08', '2019-02-01','2019-02-05']
first = dt.strptime(inp[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
out = []

for k, g in groupby(inp, key=lambda d: (dt.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") - first).days // 7 ):
    out.append(list(g))

print out
```

Output:

```
[['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'], ['2019-01-08'], ['2019-02-01'], ['2019-02-05']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt    
l1={}
for t in ts:
    week = dt.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%V")
    if week not in l1.keys():
        l1[week] = [t]
    else:
        l1[week].append(t)
out = list(l1.values())
print(out)
```

Comment: Could you offer some explanation of why this solves the problem? And how it improves upon the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby
ts=['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-08', '2019-02-01','2019-02-05']
output=[]
# strftime("%V")- returns the week 
for k,g in groupby(ts, key=lambda f: dt.strptime(f,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%V")):
    output.append(list(g))
print(output)
```